# Extending the configparser class and using a config parser in new class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, configparser

So I am trying to create a class that will have already read in the file and have all functions of configparser plus a few more.
Code looks like this:

```
import configparser
class dkconfig(configparser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clusterini = os.path.abspath("..\\cluster.ini")
        super(dkconfig,self).__init__(allow_no_value=True)
        if os.path.exists(self.clusterini):
            self.read(self.clusterini)


    def getHostnames(self):
        hostnames = {}
        for sec in self.config.sections():
            if sec.startswith("node"):
                hostnames[sec] = self.config.get(sec, "hostname")
        return hostnames
```

And its called from another script like so:

```
config = dkconfig()
names = config.getHostnames()
opts = config.options("node1")
```

The error says: `TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)` What am I missing and how can I have all instances of the "dkconfig" object already have the "cluster.ini" file read-in during construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the immediate cause of the error is that you're trying to inherit from the `configparser` *module*. You need to inherit from the *class*, not the module.

```
class dkconfig(configparser.ConfigParser):
    # ....
```

Comment: That was the part I was missing. Thanks! So yes you must specify the object you want to inherent.